# VT-x is not holding the enabled status after rebooting the Dell PowerEdge R610 server?

Tags: server, vmware, virtualization, bios, uefi

I am trying to install ESXi-6 and vCenter using the VCSA-6. I enabled the VT-x and built the ESXi, but when I am trying to install the appliances I am getting error messages due to the VT-x (Message: VT-x is disabled). But I did enable VT-x and after the restart VT-x status is changing to disabled. I am using Dell PowerEdge R610 server (2009). Please suggest me possible ways to resolve this issue. Appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about enabling something.

Comment: probably better asked on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue after enabling VT-x, try to un-plug your rack from backup battery and plug it again if it is still possible.